# Can I skip the Riftwar Legacy books?

Tags: suggested-order, riftwar-cycle

I stopped reading the Riftwar Cycle after the Serpentwar Saga, and I thought about picking it up again now.

I prefer to read everything in publication order, so the next books are the Riftwar Legacy. However, as I understand it they are not considered to be the best in the series, being based on a videogame. Is it possible to skip these books now and move on to either Legends of the Riftwar or Conlave of the Shadows without missing anything crucial?

Comment: One can - however, *you* may *not* :-)

Answer (score 3):

I did. I also skipped the Legends of the Riftwar and went straight to the Conclave series beginning with "Talon of the Silver Hawk".

I skipped the Legacy books for the same reason you did: based on a computer game. And I skipped Legends because it was side-quest stuff that looked like he was flogging a dead horse, rather than moving on.

I experienced no sense that I was missing plot points at all. Feist backclues a lot: "during the Riftwar {character} had teamed up with {other character} to {do important stuff}" so if there's anything important, he'll update you.

Hope this helps!